# query mobile web app

Tags: jquery, web-applications, web

i wrote a very simple web site for mobile devices using jquery mobile.
my question is, how do i turn it into a web app so that when the user saves it to the home screen it opens as an app instead of opening thru the safari?

thanks
Uri

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use something like Cordova (formerly PhoneGap) http://incubator.apache.org/cordova/

Comment: it seems that its not released yet.